# Writing a loop on Teradata

Tags: loops, stored-procedures, teradata

I haven't written many sprocs in Teradata, and I'm struggling to get the result I need. I'm sure though it must be a relatively easy one :)

I need to do the sum of three columns - stock, sales, and deliveries. `sales` is effectively a negative value. The result of the sum needs to give me `stock` for the next row. If the sum of the three columns <0, then I need to take 0 as the value.

Appreciate the help in advance

Here is an example of what I am trying to do in the link [stock calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDlqG.png)

`stock_for_next_week` is calculated from the sum of the three columns `stock`, `sales`, `deliveries`. And then that number needs to be used as the `stock` number for the following week, I only have the `stock` number for **week 1**. If it falls below zero, it needs to be zero (hence why cumulative sums don't work).
The calculation is partitioned by Product.

Comment: it would be nice to show what you tried

Comment: You probably don't need a loop, just show some example data and expected result

Comment: @dnoeth I added some more context to the body of the text, thank you

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the running total based on initial *stock* and weely *sales* and *deliveries*. Then calculate the running MIN over this result, if it's negative, adjust the running total:

```
SELECT ...
   running_total - 
   Min(Least(running_total, 0)) 
   Over (PARTITION BY Product
         ORDER BY Week
         ROWS Unbounded Preceding) as stock_for_next_week
FROM
 ( SELECT ...
      First_Value(stock) -- initial stock
      Over (PARTITION BY Product
            ORDER BY Week) +
      Sum(sales+deliveries) -- weekly numbers
      Over (PARTITION BY Product
            ORDER BY Week
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS running_total
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```